# Setting File's Owner to a CustomClass or NSObject?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I'm very confused about proxy objects especially `File's Owner`. So far, i've read [this](http://crazyviraj.blogspot.com/2009/05/cocoa-what-is-files-owner-in-nib.html) to be able to understand the concept of **File's Owner**. So far, i'm able to understand it in theory.

To understand better, i try to create a `CustomCell` which is a subclass of **UITableViewCell** using IB. Then, i created a **UITableView** to use my `CustomCell`. So far, i'm able to make it work.

I build this project to observe how `File's Owner` is used and how it affects .XIB files.   But, it causes more confusion than before. Because, it doesn't make any difference if i set `File's owner custom class` to `CustomCell` or just doesn't change the default class. By default,it's **NsObject**.

So, my question is, in which cases, i need to set my `File's owner custom class` to a class which is created by me.  Or, it's always supposed to set in default value. Why would i need to change this class ?

I've done my research on Web and SO. But, i didn't find any solution of this question.

Thank you.

Comment: The root class of all Objective-C classes is NSObject , which is part of the Foundation framework. but UITableViewCell is from /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework .. I don't know .. waiting for an answer!!

Comment: I'm also using `CustomTableViewCell` for my *GridView* there i've mentioned `RootViewController` it was working for me.

Comment: it's working, i just want to learn when i need to set  `File's owner` class to a different class.Read my question carefully pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the File's Owner to a custom class when you need to set values in the IBOutlets or properties of that class.  Otherwise the XIB has no way of knowing about them.

For example, when you instantiate a myViewController, it is the XIB file's owner and the UIView specified inside is instantiated and its pointer stored in the "view" property.  If you have a custom button in the XIB,  it would be instantiated its pointer stored in the IBOutlet myButton.

Comment: I think your first sentence isn't totally correct, for given example below,let's say i have `CustomCell.h/.m` and `CustomCell.xib`. Even if i didn't touch `File's Owner `object, i'm still able to set the value of **IBOutlets** by setting custom class in `CustomCell.xib`. Don't you think ?

Comment: When you create such a custom class with XIB via Xcode's 'new file' menu entry, Xcode presets the class of the file's owner for you.  If the file's owner was set to standard class from which you inherit, you can access the IBOutlets from that class and further up the inheritance tree.